# Date in String to Date in Date conversion

Tags: java, date

I'm having date in `String` format as `"2019-10-30 12:17:47"`. I want to convert this to an instance of `Date` along with the time so that I can compare two date obejcts.

This is what I've tried:

```
String dateString = "2019-10-30 12:17:47"        //Date in String format
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd  HH-mm-ss");    //sdf
Date d1 = format.parse(dateString);
```

But here I'm getting exception as "Unparseble date exception".

Kindly help...

Comment: The `String` doesn't match the pattern, there is a difference between `:` and `-` in the time part...

Comment: In addition, your SDF mask has an extra space in between the date and time components, which does not appear in the string date your are trying to convert.

Comment: Please don't use the error-prone and buggy `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` classes. They have been supplanted by much better classes since Java 8. Look into [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) classes.

Answer (score 3):

### What went wrong in your code?

In your format pattern string, `yyyy-MM-dd  HH-mm-ss`, you have got two spaces between the date and the time. Since your date string, `2019-10-30 12:17:47`, has got only one space there, your formatter objects by throwing the exception. This was also what Tim Biegeleisen said in a comment. The comment by deHaar is true too: The hyphens between hour, minute and second don’t match the colons in your date string either.

### What to do instead?

See [the good answer by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58620392/5772882)

Answer (score 2):

You should really switch to `java.time` (as already suggested in one of the comments below your question). It isn't more difficult than the outdated temporal classes from `java.util` but less error-prone and more powerful concerning offsets, time zones, daylight saving time and the multitude of different calendars the world has.

See this little example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateString = "2019-10-30 12:17:47";
    // define your pattern, should match the one of the String ;-)
    String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    // parse the datetime using the pattern
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString,
                                            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern));

    // print it using a different (here a built-in) formatting pattern
    System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
    // or you just use the one defined by you
    System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern)));
    // or you define another one for the output
    System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy HH-mm-ss")));
}
```

The output on my system looks like this:

```
2019-10-30T12:17:47
2019-10-30 12:17:47
Okt 30 2019 12-17-47
```

Answer (score 1):

The date in string you want to format does not match the formatter. See more detail here, 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

```
@Test
public void test2() {
    String dateString = "2019-10-30 12:17:47";        //Date in String format
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");    //sdf
    try {
        Date d1 = format.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: From your link I noticed: *This Date and Time section uses the date and time APIs in the `java.util` package. The `java.time` APIs, available in the JDK 8 release, provides a comprehensive date and time model that offers significant improvements over the java.util classes. The java.time APIs are described in the Date Time trail. The Legacy Date-Time Code page might be of particular interest.*

Comment: These date-time classes used here are terrible. They were supplanted years ago by the industry-leading *java.time* classes. See the modern solutions in Answers by deHaar, and by Ole V.V.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Prior to the Java SE 8 release, the date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar` had several drawbacks, like not type safe , mutable. It would be better to use the date-time APIs in  `java.time` package since JDK 8. But I think he should know why he got the exception and  know the syntax of formatting time if he is learning JAVA. @BasilBourque

Answer (score 0):

**There are two ways to do it**

first is  your way

```
    String dateString = "2019-10-30 12:17:47"; // Date in String format
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); // sdf
    Date d1 = format.parse(dateString
```

second is my way (Local date)

```
    LocalDate resultDate = dateFormat("2019-10-30 12:17:47");
    System.out.println(resultDate);
```

```
  public static LocalDate dateFormat(String textTypeDateTime) {

    final DateTimeFormatter dateTimetextFormatter =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return LocalDate.parse(textTypeDateTime, dateTimetextFormatter);
  }
```

Comment: Using java.time is a good idea. `LocalDate` is not the right choice since it doesn’t store a time of day, so we are losing some information from the string. Use `LocalDateTIme` instead.